# How do I customize zsh's vim mode?

Tags: vim, zsh

Ok, so I finally made the great change.  In my .zshenv, I changed my EDITOR:

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

There are a couple of questions I have that are so minor that I didn't want to start separate questions for them.  Here they are:

1. How do I get zsh to distinguish between insert mode and command mode like in vim?  Preferably this would change the cursor from an underline to a block like in vim, but displaying text at the bottom would work as well.
2. How do I get it to act more like vim?  For instance, I'd rather it be in command mode by default and not go out of it after one command.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**1.**) (see http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/zlewidgets and http://pthree.org/2009/03/28/add-vim-editing-mode-to-your-zsh-prompt/ ):

```
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    RPS1="${${KEYMAP/vicmd/-- NORMAL --}/(main|viins)/-- INSERT --}"
    RPS2=$RPS1
    zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select
```

Where:

- "RPS" stands for 'right prompt string' and defines the prompt appearing on the right hand side of the terminal, and the ${variable/pattern/replacement} syntax is that of 'parameter expansion', see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameter_Operations.
- 'zle -N' causes the user-definable widgets 'zle-line-init' and 'zle-keymap-select' to be bound (to shell functions of same names), so that they will be called when the line editor is initialised and the keymap is changed respectively, see: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#SEC125.

**2.**) i suspect that you have to write another zsh-widget to do that, get inspired by the first of the two links for the first problem.

Answer (score 23):

akira's solution has the following problem when using multi-line prompts: when going from ins to cmd mode, the prompt redraw causes few lines to be deleted from the previous output (and the new prompt is displayed few lines above). How many lines depends on how many lines you have in your prompt.

The way to deal with that is to use `zle-line-finish`, without using `zle reset-prompt` there. An example:

```
# perform parameter expansion/command substitution in prompt
setopt PROMPT_SUBST

vim_ins_mode="[INS]"
vim_cmd_mode="[CMD]"
vim_mode=$vim_ins_mode

function zle-keymap-select {
  vim_mode="${${KEYMAP/vicmd/${vim_cmd_mode}}/(main|viins)/${vim_ins_mode}}"
  zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select

function zle-line-finish {
  vim_mode=$vim_ins_mode
}
zle -N zle-line-finish
```

And then you can add it to your right-prompt, for example:

```
RPROMPT='${vim_mode}'
```

This is straight from my blog post about it:

- http://pawelgoscicki.com/archives/2012/09/vi-mode-indicator-in-zsh-prompt/

Comment: This answer should get a lot of votes. This is the first time I've seen this solution, and it works where the others don't. I spent an hour fiddling around with the `zle-line-init` widget to no avail. Changed it to match what Pawel provided and bingo!

Comment: Thanks! It still isn't 100% bulletproof - from time to time I experience a situation where some lines from my previous output are deleted - but it happens so rarely that I just ignore it.

Comment: `RPROMPT2` should be set as well so that the status is displayed in 
continuation lines. Also, when using this you may want to do `setopt 
transient_rprompt` so that modes for previously accepted lines aren't displayed.

Comment: One thing that is still missing: If I switch back to emacs mode (`bindkey -e`) it still shows `[INS]`.

Comment: @Daniel That's sort-of intentional. Why would I *ever* want to switch back to emacs mode?!

Comment: Well, I am not yet completely set, old habits die hard... It would just help me to do the transition if I can visualize if I am in insert, command or weird :-) mode.

Comment: My right prompt is stuck on "INS" with this solution.

Comment: @cheflo you can see my current version of this setup here: https://github.com/pjg/dotfiles/blob/master/.zshrc#L518-L584 -- maybe that will help you

Comment: I got it working using akira's solution for now, but thanks for linking your dotfile. I will try it if I run into troubles.

Comment: For those starting their `.zshrc` from scratch you will want to enable `setopt PROMPT_SUBST` and maintain single quotes for `RPROMPT` like above for the example to work.

Answer (score 5):

```
zle-line-init() { zle -K vicmd; }
zle -N zle-line-init
```

these two lines make sure it starts in command mode

Comment: Does not work, zsh starts in insert mode anyway

Answer (score 1):

The below will set you up with a modified cursor and a prompt displaying which mode you are in. You can change `DEFAULT_VI_MODE` to either `viins` or `vicmd`. Just paste the below into a fresh `.zshrc` to get started:

```
# Prefer vi shortcuts
bindkey -v
DEFAULT_VI_MODE=viins
KEYTIMEOUT=1

__set_cursor() {
    local style
    case $1 in
        reset) style=0;; # The terminal emulator's default
        blink-block) style=1;;
        block) style=2;;
        blink-underline) style=3;;
        underline) style=4;;
        blink-vertical-line) style=5;;
        vertical-line) style=6;;
    esac

    [ $style -ge 0 ] && print -n -- "\e[${style} q"
}

# Set your desired cursors here...
__set_vi_mode_cursor() {
    case $KEYMAP in
        vicmd)
          __set_cursor block
          ;;
        main|viins)
          __set_cursor vertical-line
          ;;
    esac
}

__get_vi_mode() {
    local mode
    case $KEYMAP in
        vicmd)
          mode=NORMAL
          ;;
        main|viins)
          mode=INSERT
          ;;
    esac
    print -n -- $mode
}

zle-keymap-select() {
    __set_vi_mode_cursor
    zle reset-prompt
}

zle-line-init() {
    zle -K $DEFAULT_VI_MODE
}

zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select

# Optional: allows you to open the in-progress command inside of $EDITOR
autoload -Uz edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd 'v' edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line

# PROMPT_SUBST enables functions and variables to re-run everytime the prompt
# is rendered
setopt PROMPT_SUBST

# Single quotes are important so that function is not run immediately and saved
# in the variable
RPROMPT='$(__get_vi_mode)'
```

Note: I only tested this in Terminal.app (2.7.3) on MacOS (10.12.6) with zsh (5.3.1). Also, if you ever add `edit-command-line` then the mode will be correctly set too.