# How to switch comfortably to vi command mode on the zsh command line?

Tags: command-line, zsh, vi

In vi, I have mapped 'jj' to escape to be able to switch to command mode without using the annoying escape key. Now I want to have the same for command line editing for which I use vi-mode. I already have found the following solution:

```
bindkey '^j' vi-cmd-mode
```

lets you change with control-j into command mode. Still searching for a solution without modifier-keys as 'jj' or something similar.

Comment: Why not just remapping Caps Lock to Escape?

Comment: I can't use the escape key because iTerm needs it for sending meta :(

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Note: You should look at `man zshzle` for a lot of goodies about customizing `bindkey` and emulating `GNU readline`.

This is how I mapped `jj` to `Esc`:

```
bindkey -M viins 'jj' vi-cmd-mode
```

If you're interested in distinguishing between insert-mode and normal-mode, you could try out the suggestion akira mentions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/151803/how-do-i-customize-zshs-vim-mode/156204#156204)

Comment: yeah! works perfectly. thx alot!

Comment: Are there any prerequisites that need to be fulfilled before this works in zsh? Or ways to debug the key bindings? After inserting this command, nothing happens. jj still doesn't work.

Comment: I had KEYTIMEOUT set too low, that was the reason.

Comment: @Ultramaster makes a great point. If you're already setting the KEYTIMEOUT for speed, I'd recommend >= 20 milliseconds. Such as `export KEYTIMEOUT=20`