# ZSH+gnome-terminal and VI input mode: Show ibeam or block cursor

Tags: zsh, gnome-terminal

[Different methods exist](https://superuser.com/questions/151803/how-do-i-customize-zshs-vim-mode) to show if you're in insert or normal when using VI key binding in ZSH.

Gnome-terminal also [allows you to change the caret](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504240/how-to-change-the-caret-of-the-gnome-terminal) from block `█` to ibeam `|` with a call to `gconftool-2`.

How can I combine these two so that I have an ibeam in insert mode and a block in normal mode?

Comment: I've included links to my research. I've not attempted it myself. Stackoverflow does not require you show any previous efforts since this is not a homework forum.

Comment: I've just asked because if you have an own approach it might be more helpful for you, if we can concentrate on your specific problem. And no just giving another copy&paste snippet. But here you are...

Comment: I see, I misunderstood you. I have little understanding of zhs and it wasn't important enough for me to spend the time to get into it. I'm sure other might like this idea so I just posted it. It works great by the way! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting both answers provided in the question [[1](https://superuser.com/a/156204/195224), [2]](https://askubuntu.com/a/504288)
 together, I end up with this:

```
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    if [[ $KEYMAP == vicmd ]]; then
       gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape block
    elif [[ $KEYMAP == (main|viins) ]]; then
       gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape ibeam
    fi
}
zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select
```

The difference is that I check the `$KEYMAP` parameter directly with an `if..fi` clause and execute the `gconftool-2` command instead of altering the prompt.

Comment: Using gconftool to modify the profile has the significant drawback that it immediately influences all other gnome-terminal tabs or windows that use the same profile.

Answer (score 4):

In recent versions of gnome-terminal, you can use the following escape sequences to change the cursor:

- `\e[0 q` or `\e[ q`: reset to whatever's defined in the profile settings
- `\e[1 q`: blinking block
- `\e[2 q`: steady block
- `\e[3 q`: blinking underline
- `\e[4 q`: steady underline
- `\e[5 q`: blinking I-beam
- `\e[6 q`: steady I-beam

You can print these by e.g. `echo -ne '\e[5 q'`. Hook these up to your zsh configuration as shown in mpy's answer.